# Integrate Location based AR in an Existing App

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to the AR world. We have an App that has a huge audience. We have already implemented a custom mapping system where we can navigate the user to our almost 700K POS locations countrywide. Now we want to integrate an AR solution into our existing app where users can see the nearest POS locations using an AR camera. For this, we want to create an outdoor AR and an indoor AR solution.

For the Outdoor Solution, we want to use the existing location of our POS those are usually beside the roads. But for the indoor service where GPS usually does not work properly, we want to use a service like Vuforia or something else. For the indoor solution, users can able see different custom advertisements and POS locations within a supermarket or big mall. They can also be guided by the AR navigation to a specific POS where a special promotion is going on.

This should be used strictly within our app or can be used as an app-in-app service. As I stated earlier I am new to the Augmented Reality world please suggest to me the best way I can start. Even if this is not the perfect forum to ask this question please let me know where I can get help. If there is any vendor or solution that can help us you can also suggest that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on the huge audience for your app. You didn’t mention what platform(s) your app nor custom mapping system are built on, so take all this with a large grain of salt.

For the integration of outdoor mapping, indoor mapping, and augmented reality, Microsoft’s Azure platform has a lot going for it. It has a full set of [map services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-maps), including the Creator resource (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/azure/azure-maps-creator) that enables you to create live maps from floor plan drawings.

For the augmented reality part: While Azure has industrial-strength services for really technical 3D mixed reality stuff, there’s a third-party app platform, [UniteAR](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/ibosoninnovationsprivatelimited1630056149613.unitear), that plays nicely with Azure – maybe even with what you're using for your app.

Again, this might not help you at all, but maybe it will be useful to someone earlier in their app development.